# Share in facebook using Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I need to share text, Image And link without using "SLComposeViewController" in Swift.

I have used Parse for this. But don't able to Post

Below is my Code:

```
func postToFacebook(message : String) {

        var postParams =
        ["https://developers.facebook.com/ios" : "link",
            "https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png":"picture",
            "Facebook SDK for iOS":"name",
            message: "message",
            "Build great social apps and get more installs.":"caption",
            "The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps." : "description",
        ];

        let req = FBRequest(session: PFFacebookUtils.session(), graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: postParams, HTTPMethod: "POST")
        req.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println("\(error.description)")
            } else {
                println("posted to facebook")
            }
        }    
    }
```

And getting this Error:

```
error = {
     code = 200;
     message = "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action";
     type = OAuthException;
};
```

Please anybody help on doing this

Comment: You need the publish_actions permission in order to post to me/feed. Do you have that permission?

Comment: On setting "publish_action" I am getting this warning "It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days"